# Changing the VSCode Default Formatter to put array items on a new line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Can we change the VSCode default formatter for Javascript such that it puts array items on a new line?

For example I have this:

```
const mm = [MatCardModule, MatSnackBarModule, MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatStepperModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatGridListModule];
```

And when the document is formatted all the modules stay on the same line instead of being moved to new lines.  This is OK if the line is a certain width, but if it's above say 600px, I'd like all the items put on a new line.

Comment: Have you tried the prettier formatter? In his options, you can define a max length. If your code is longer, he will split it up to new lines.

Comment: Not yet - I was hoping there was a way to do it with the default formatter, because when I start installing extensions there's the possibility of loosing something else that I like.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like that ?

```
const mm = [ MatCardModule
           , MatSnackBarModule
           , MatSelectModule
           , MatButtonModule
           , MatToolbarModule
           , MatStepperModule
           , MatFormFieldModule
           , MatInputModule
           , MatGridListModule
           ]
```

Im made my own formater for small js parts like this one, but implementing this in a code beautyfier is a big chalenge with a lot of time.